# Select nodes matching one of several conditions (OR)

Tags: haskell, xml-conduit

Using `Text.XML.Cursor`, is there a convenient way of selecting nodes matching one of *several* conditions (like an `or` function)?

How can I get the cursors of all `<p class="myclass">` **and** `<h1>` nodes (in the right order) in the following example?

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <div></div>
    <h1></h1>
    <hr>
    <p class="myclass"></p>
    <h1></h1>
</div>

extract :: Cursor -> [Cursor]
-- Returns 3 cursors [h1, p, h1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `checkElement` which accepts a predicate.

```
checkElement :: Boolean b => (Element -> b) -> Axis
```

So with that, and knowing that your `extract` is an `Axis`<sup>1</sup>:

```
extract :: Axis
extract = checkElement yourPredicate
  where
    yourPredicate (Element name _ _) = any (== name) ["p", "h1"]`
```

Adding the class check should be easy then; match the 2nd element from `Element` constructor, look for the `class` attribute, then inspect its value for `myclass` presence.

---

<sup>1</sup> [`type Axis = Cursor -> [Cursor]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.5.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html#Axis)

Comment: use [checkName](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.9.1.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html#v:checkName) and [attributeIs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.9.1.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html#v:attributeIs)